# Batch renaming files from different variables

Tags: variables, batch-file, batch-rename

I have text file (2.txt) with even number of lines. Odd lines are current names of the files that I need renamed (odd lines contain file extension). Even lines are new names of the corresponding files (even lines DO NOT contain file extension).

E.g. of such file:

001.mp3

First song.

002.mp3

I am a song, too!

003.mp3

He's the one who will rename me...

(end of file)

I want to loop through file, read the line into variable, check if it contains extension (mp3). If yes (odd line), then save it to "name" variable. If not (even line), then save it to "line" variable with dot and extension added to the end (e.g., First song..mp3) and rename "name" file into "line" file. Thus "001.mp3" will be renamed to "First song..mp3".

I tried to combine different parts of the code from different sources, but something goes wrong.

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN (2.txt) DO (
  set var=%%i
  if not x%var:mp3=%==x%var% set name=%%i
  if x%var:mp3=%==x%var% (
    set line=%%i.mp3
    ren name line
  )
)
pause
```

Comment: So is it 1.txt or 2.txt

Comment: 2.txt. I have many of them due to many tests with code going right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is some tricky code.  Hopefully you will understand it.

I used this as my 2.txt file

```
001.mp3
First song
002.mp3
I am a song
003.mp3
last song
004.mp3
my final! song
```

And here is my code.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableExtensions enableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" "2.txt"') do set "lines=%%~a"
set /a "lines=lines / 2"

< 2.txt (
   for /L %%l in (1, 1, %lines%) do (
      set "line1="
      set "line2="
      set /P "line1="
      set /P "line2="
      echo rename "!line1!" "!line2!.mp3"
   )
)

endlocal
Pause
```

My output

```
rename "001.mp3" "First song.mp3"
rename "002.mp3" "I am a song.mp3"
rename "003.mp3" "last song.mp3"
rename "004.mp3" "my final! song.mp3"
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Remove the ECHO before the rename command if you feel the output on the screen looks good.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. It works with your example, yet creates a mess out of my data. It creates something like this: rename "001.mp3 \N Name1.mp3" "002.mp3 \N Name2.mp3". Where could be the problem?

Comment: Without seeing your real data it would be very hard to troubleshoot. I have no idea if your file is plain ascii text file or unicode.  Nor do I know if each line in your file is terminated with a carriage return and line feed.

Comment: Aha, checked for CR LF. Some lanes only contained LF. Culprit found, now it shows correct renaming patter. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=" %%a in (2.txt) do (
  set "$Line=%%a" 
   If /i [!$Line:~-4!]==[.mp3] (
       set "$FileMp3=%%a"
       ) else (
                  echo ren "!$FileMp3!" "%%a.mp3"
                  )
   )
)
```

If the output is correct remove the `echo`

Comment: You can just use the Command Modifiers instead of trying to get a substring of the line. `If /i [%%~xa]==[.mp3]`